# Install libxcb from source

Tags: compiling

I try to install libxcb from source, but I have an error, I do not understand why, this the error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (pthread-stubs xau >= 0.99.2) were not met:

No package 'xau' found
```

I have installed from source [pthread-stubs](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xcb/pthread-stubs/snapshot/pthread-stubs-0.3.tar.gz) and [proto-xcb-proto](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xcb/proto/snapshot/xcb-proto-1.9.tar.gz)

This is to install `qtile`. At the moment I use Debian wheezy but I will soon use jessie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the headers from the pthreads and xau packages. You can get these from installing the `-dev` version of the respective packages.

The easiest thing to do however is to make sure you have a `deb-src` line in you `sources.list` and run:

```
apt-get build-dep libxcb
```

which will install all of the necessary packages to build xcb.

Comment: Thanks it works, I have another problem, but it's not the same, thanks again.